# Check if a collection contains at least one document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am currently trying to programm a Login in Meteor (yes I know of the default login package). Wenn a user presses Submit on the Login Form, a Meteor Method call is done:

```
Template.Login.events({
"submit form": function(event, doc){
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = doc.find("#login-username").value;
    var password = doc.find("#login-password").value;
    Meteor.call("isAdmin",username,password, function(error, result){
        console.log("Catchback from Method Call: ");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(result);
    });
}
});
```

And the Meteor method, that is supposed to check if the collection contains the entry:

```
Meteor.methods({
  isAdmin: function (username, password){
      return !!Admins.find({username: username, password: password});   
  }
});
```

The problem is now, that I just can't figure out a way to just return true, when the collection contains an entry for this user, and false if not. It currently just returns true for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`collection.find([selector], [options])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) function returns a cursor. As a result, you could use [`collection.find([selector], [options]).count()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/), which returns the count of documents that matched the `find()` query. In further consequence, you could check if this count value is greater zero.

In your case:

```
Meteor.methods({
  isAdmin: function (username, password){
      return Admins.find({username: username, password: password}).count() > 0; 
  }
});
```